# [Cucumber][Execution]How to run particular scenario outline as last script in a suite

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java

I have a suite for particular feature.
Here is my feature file structure.
FeatureFile1.feature

[image: Feature file format]

Like this I have two more feature files as - FeatureFile2.feature and FeatureFile3.feature

Now from FeatureFile1.feature, I have to run @Tag4 at the end, i.e. after execution of FeatureFile3.feature.

So is there any explicit way in which I can mention at feature level or at step-definition level which will run tag4 scenario outline after last scenario executed of featurefile3.feature?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using selective feature file or selective scenarios in the feature using tags
so you need tags at feature file level which will run your entire feature file then the another tag for running your desired scenario

[image]

For Ex:

```
 @CucumberOptions(features= "src/main/resources/publish", tags="@FeatureFile3, @FF1scenario2",  format = {"pretty"} )
```

This will run the Feature file 3 and scenario 2 in feature file 1

Comment: ya so it will be like, every time if I run that suite I have to mention the tags in my testrunner, what I want is, just single tag should be used and sequencing will be managed by some ordering on features I have mentioned in feature file.